# How to select with the length of the field / untrim using select

Tags: postgresql, select

I have this table that I would like to select values from. The thing is that I would like to get the exact amount of length in the output of my select as I have in my table.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.test_table
(
 id serial NOT NULL,
 otyp CHARACTER VARYING(3),
 fname CHARACTER VARYING(8),
 age integer
) WITH(OIDS=FALSE);
```

And let's say that this table contain

```
 id | otyp | fname  | age 
----+------+--------+-----
  1 | aa   | gustav |  20
(1 row)
```

```
SELECT id || otyp || fname || age FROM myschema.test_table;
```

This would give me this result:

```
1aagustav20
```

I want the output to be

```
1aa gustav  20
```

Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

```
SELECT id 
   || RPAD(otyp, 3, ' ') 
   || RPAD(fname, 8, ' ') 
   || age 
FROM 
    myschema.test_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
SELECT id || otyp || ' ' || fname || ' ' || age FROM myschema.test_table;
```

Comment: That would help me only for the row above, what would I do if I have several rows with different values?

Comment: Why the above would not work with other rows? Anyway seems to me that you defined your problem wrongly. Output formatting should not be handled on SQL level.